# Does PHP simplexml_import_dom convert the full DOM?

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML document I am importing into a PHP DOM and validating with XSD (RelaxNG is not an option). I then want to turn the DOM into simpleXML for processing. The function simplexml_import_dom seems to be the thing to use, but the documentation says "This function takes a node of a DOM document and makes it into a SimpleXML node." This implies that only one node is converted, not the full DOM tree. Is this correct?

I could get the XML as simpleXML by re-reading the file, but that would be wasteful.  If simplexml_import_dom does not do the full DOM tree, how do I convert the DOM to simpleXML? I've looked for example code for recursive DOM traversal but have not found any examples. Any suggestions?

Comment: So long as your DOM has a single root node then you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML objects/elements/nodes include their children. The simplexml_import_dom function handles the recursion for you.